# Why aren't array elements not deleted in forEach loop logged in the console?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to delete the first and third elements of the array using the `forEach` method. I was able to do this, but the question came to me: Why are elements deleted in `forEach` registered in the console but elements that were not deleted are not registered in the console?

Does not the `forEach` method apply to all elements of a functional array? So why aren't all the array elements registered in the console?

```
const cartItems = ['Book1', 'Book2', 'Book3', 'Book4']

cartItems.forEach(function (item, index, array) {

    // I mean console.log below 

    console.log(item)

    if (index == 0) {
        array.shift()
    }

    if (index == 1) {
        array.splice(1, 1)
    }
})

console.log(cartItems)
```

Comment: Because `shift()` and `splice()` mutate the original array.

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, it's not a good idea to modify the array walked over by `forEach` (or any other iterative function). Here's a telling quote from [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#description):

> The range of elements processed by forEach() is set before the first
> invocation of callbackFn. **Elements which are assigned to indexes
> already visited, or to indexes outside the range, will not be visited by callbackFn.**

In your example, the callback function of `forEach` is skipped for 'Book2' item because `array.shift` essentially reassigns it to index 0 (which has already been visited). The same thing happens with 'Book4' after `array.splice`.

Answer (score 1):

You must notice the definition of `shift` and `splice` method. Based on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp) the definition of `shift` is:

> The shift() method removes the first item of an array.
>
> Note: **This method changes the length of the array**.
>
> Note: The return value of the shift method is the removed item.
>
> Note: **This method will change the original array**.

And the same as `splice` method is:

> The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns
> the removed item(s).
>
> Note: **This method changes the original array**.

And the answer for your question `why aren't all the array elements registered in the console?` is that both methods change the original array.